# Is there a way to resolve a module in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am a beginner to React Native, and I encountered an error. It says that is it is Unable to resolve module `react-native-screens` from `node_modules/react-navigation stack/lib/module/vendor/views/Stack/CardStack.js` It then tells me how to fix it, but these don't work. Can you please help?

Here is the simulator:

[image]

And here are my two files:

App.js:

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {HomeScreen} from './components/HomeScreen';
import {LoginScreen} from './components/HomeScreen';
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view';
import {
  Colors,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
render() {
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <View style={styles.sectionContainer2}>
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img1.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img2.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img3.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img4.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img7.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./images/img8.jpg')} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
        </>
  );
};
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you linked the module? And double check if it's installed if react-native resolves without problem but not another package...

Comment: Did you install ```react-native-screens```? if not try installing ```npm install react-native-screens --save```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/troubleshooting.html#im-getting-an-error-unable-to-resolve-module-after-updating-to-the-latest-version

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.